# foreach: "in" v. "as"

Tags: php, foreach

What is the difference between these two usages of foreach?

```
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
 //do stuff
}

foreach ($odp in $ftw) {
  //do more stuff
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First one is legal PHP, second one [is not](http://us.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score 7):

Using `in` in PHP doesn't work. In Javascript however, a similar form is acceptable and they differ thusly:

```
var obj = {
    'a' : 'Apple',
    'b' : 'Banana',
    'c' : 'Carrot'
};

for (var i in obj) {
    alert(i); // "a", "b", "c"
}

for each (var i in obj) {
    alert(i); // "Apple", "Banana", "Carrot"
}
```

basically, `for each ... in ...` (Javascript) or `foreach ... as ...` (PHP) will give the value of the properties of the object, whereas `for ... in ...` (javascript) will give you the name of each property.